# Trace object /ROI from from binary or grayscale Image matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have the following image . I want to trace the part which is shown in red lines and remove it from the image . but I don't know how I can scan from top to bottom to find the object and remove it. can anyone help me to do this ???

The object has a property that it has bright reflection and dark shadow behind it, can we use this information ?

Thanks in advance for helping me

[image: first part is gray scale and second part is its binary form]

**Another view case**

[image]

Comment: If you have a video, try optical flow

Comment: no i have pictures not video